# Jasper Report with sum of Field used in another Group

Tags: jasper-reports

I need to do sum of Qte Cde field in Group flag_date_depasses define with number 2 in below image.

I have tried following: taken variable and add Quantity in one variable and reset this variable when group flag_date_depassed changes.

[image]

Just need the sum of Quantity in another Group.

Answer (score 1):

You must have forgotten to add the aggregate variable itself in the variable summation expression:

1. Create a variable that will hold the summation of the field `qte_cde` (let's call it `sum_qte_cde`)
2. Specify the variable expression of `sum_qte_cde` as `$V{sum_qte_cde} + $F{qte_cde}`
3. Set the Reset type of the variable `sum_qte_cde` to Group.
4. Display `sum_qte_cde` as `TOTAL BL`